# Visual Studio C Programing LNK1104 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Follow the steps where I opened a new C project:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqK0tp6MQ6Q 
The first time running the not error but then I get an error. 
No application is not running in the background
[image]

Comment: You'll need to make an exclusion in your anti-malware so it won't prevent VS from writing executable files before it is done scanning them.  If it is Avast then just get rid of it completely.

Comment: I do not use any antivirus program.

Comment: Then your machine is pretty sick.  You need the geek squad, not a programmer.  It can't write the file, there is no good remaining reason why it couldn't.

Comment: Make sure your `answer.exe` app is not running.  Try to delete it from the disk, in fact.  Rarely, Visual Studio is the one using the file.  Try to close it and restart it to see if that fixes the problem.